# How to auto detect a remote IMAP/POP3 server given only a hostname in PHP

Tags: php

I am using the function imap_open in PHP.

```
$hostname = '{hostname.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'user@gmail.com';
$password = 'password'; 

$inbox = @imap_open($hostname,$username,$password);
```

Is there a way to scan:

Port number: 993
Mail type: IMAP
SSL
Path prefix: INBOX

By giving only the hostname?

In this way the customer doesn't need to know these tings. He just writes the hostname and the rest of information shows up automatically.